# Is there any way to get around name collisions in nested structures in my Mustache.js templates?

Tags: javascript, mustache

I'm really having problems with name collisions in my Mustache templates (using Mustache.js).  This example illustrates those two problems:

I'm passing this data:

```
{'recs': {'code': 'foo', 'id': 1
          'childRecs': [{'id': 2},
                        {'code': 'bar', 'id': 3}]
         }
}
```

Into this template:

```
{{#recs}}
  Record ID: {{id}}
  {{#childRecs}}
    This child code is: [{{code}}] and its parent ID is: {{id}}
  {{/childRecs}}
{{/recs}}
```

Expected:

```
Record ID: 1
This child code is: [] and its parent ID is 1
This child code is: [bar] and its parent ID is 1
```

Actual:

```
Record ID: 1
This child code is [foo] and its parent ID is 2
This child code is [bar] and its parent ID is 3
```

1. There is no way in the nested `{{#childRecs}}` block to access the parent `{{#recs}}{id}}{{/recs}}` field -- it is overwritten by the `{{#childRecs}}{{id}}{{/childRecs}}`
2. If a variable in `{{#childRecs}}` is missing, and a parent variable of the same name exists, there is no way to prevent it from printing the parent variable.

My nested structures are very deep and there are many name collisions, so renaming them in such a way that they do not collide is not a viable option.  Is there any other way to solve my problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two options:

- Enrich the data on the client-side before sending it for rendering. For instance,
  you can loop over all the childRecs and add a new parentId property - and then update
  your template accordingly, or
- Use http://www.handlebarsjs.com/ - it keeps the mustache syntax but adds a few goodies like  accessing the parent context (through `../`). For instance:

  ```
  {{#recs}}
      Record ID: {{id}}
      {{#childRecs}}
          This child code is: [{{code}}] and its parent ID is: {{../id}}
      {{/childRecs}}
  {{/recs}}
  ```

Comment: I ended up writing a wrapper around Mustache.to_html which recursively renames each property of the data object by prepending a number of periods equal to the depth.  Then I modified my template to match. This way I have to explicitly specify the depth each time I use a variable in the template, and variables are all unique. Handlebars.js looks tempting -- not sure if ../ is the *only* way to access parent properties, or if it falls back by default if no such property exists on the child. I dislike fallback. Unfortunately there does not appear to be a mature PHP parser for Handlebar templates.

Comment: Originally I was going to add a parentId property to each object to reference its parent, but the problem I ran into was when nesting was several levels deep -- there was no way to repeatedly traverse up the tree to a grandparent.  Mustache.js does not allow nested tags with the same name, e.g. {{#parentId}}{{#parentId}}{{val}}{{/parentId}}{{/parentId}}, but for a single level that would work.

Comment: I ran into the same issue and just added values to my view. {{catID}} is now a field within my {{sub-cat}} view. It works ....although its another DB call I rather not make.